# Отследить клик на div

Tags: javascript

Есть разметка с предметами.

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="itemHolder"></div>
    <div class="itemHolder"></div>
    <div class="itemHolder"></div>
    <div class="itemHolder"></div>
    <div class="itemHolder"></div>
</div>
```

Мне надо отследить клик на любой `div` с классом `itemHolder` и после выполнить скрипт.

```
var val = document.getElementById("item_name").innerHTML;
```

Я повесил `addEventListener` на весь `document`, но как отследить что кликнули именно на `div` с классом `itemHolder`, а не на любой дугой `div`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, какое отношение событие `DOMSubtreeModified` имеет к клику на элемент с классом `itemHolder`.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified" (может быть "click"?), function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  if (e.target.classList.contains('itemHolder')) {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

На клик немного другое событие. А вообще его можно просто повесить на эти дивы. Не обязательно все клики проверять.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.className=="itemHolder") {
   alert("click");
   //ваши действия
  }
});
```

```css
.itemHolder {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="itemHolder">123</div>
    <div class="itemHolder">345</div>
    <div class="itemHolder">567</div>
    <div class="itemHolder">888</div>
    <div class="itemHolder">999</div>
</div>
```